# Why did Adrian Veidt choose such an obvious password?

Tags: dc, character-motivation, watchmen

In *Watchmen*, Rorschach (Kovacs) and Nite Owl (Daniel) discover Ozymandias' (Veidt) plan after breaking into his office computer.  The password he used was incredibly easy to crack:  Rameses II.  There was a book of that title on the shelf beside his desk, and he was known to be obsessed with Egyptology, Pharaohs, etc.  Even worse, his superhero name - Ozymandias - is the Greek version of the name Rameses II.  Considering the fact that he's supposed to be the smartest man on earth, it appears that he *wanted* his former colleagues to uncover his plans.

After their discovery, Nite Owl and Rorschach head to Veidt's headquarters in Antarctica.  As a result, they aren't killed in the attack on New York City.  This might be interpreted as a sign that Veidt is still fond of his former colleagues, and doesn't want them to die.  When Daniel visits Veidt earlier in the story, Veidt does seem to be genuinely happy to see his old friend, which could lend some support to this idea;  on the other hand, Veidt is nothing if not a duplicitous schemer, so he could have been putting on a show to allay suspicions.

However, the fact that Nite Owl and Rorschach survive the attack on NYC puts Veidt's plans in jeopardy, because they might tell the world what really happened, which would render Veidt's scheme useless and provoke the very war he was trying to prevent.  In order for the plan to work, Veidt needs Dr. Manhattan alive and willing to go along with it, but the fates of the other Watchmen is largely irrelevant - in fact, it would be slightly better, from Veidt's perspective, if the other Watchmen were dead and unable to expose the plot.

So here's the question:

### Why did Veidt use such an obvious password?  It seems clear that he wanted Nite Owl and Rorschach to find him out, but why?

Comment: Genius (and vanity) requires an audience.

Comment: Because he's a schmuck

Comment: Hey it was the 80s!  Is this any worse than a teenage boy being able to access the WOPR at NORAD using Joshua?

Comment: I don’t think it’s a *terrible* password, even given his superhero name, or his obsession with Egyptology. By office PC standards, it’s almost certainly above average. This doesn’t mean that it’s a *good* password of course. — Particularly given that his is a high-risk system for breach attempts. But in the historic context, at the time it’s unlikely that many systems (even such important ones) had better passwords.

Comment: I suspect it's because Alan Moore doesn't own a computer and has no interest in the finer points of password protection, but needed to move the plot along.

Comment: It's the 1980s. A lot of people - even smart people - back then didn't have a clue when it came to computers. They might have known just about enough to do their own jobs and maybe load a few games. Password complexity was not a very high priority, and compared to a lot  of passwords like "password" and "letmein" and "god" (the last which I heard a lot of sys admins would use!) which were knocking around at the time, "rameses ii" is actually pretty cryptic!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The very short answer is that while Adrian may be a genius, he does have the classic supervillain '*Achilles heel*' when it comes to his obsession with history. Not only does he model *himself* on Ozymandias but he puts his plan at severe risk through his choice of names for the various parts of his scheme;

- **Pyramid** Deliveries (the shell company he's using to pay those involved in the scheme)
- **Karnak** (his Antarctic hideout)
- **Rameses II** (his password)

There's no special indication in the graphic novel that he's *expecting* to have his computer system cracked although it has to be admitted that his security **absolutely sucks**.

[image]

In the film, it's even less likely given that he has what appears to be gay pornography on his desktop

[image]

Comment: Re:  the files in the movie version - maybe he's out and proud?

Comment: @WadCheber - I don't believe that to be the case

Comment: Wow--I'd imagine the folks at [Information Security SE](http://security.stackexchange.com) would have something to say about that "password incomplete" message!

Comment: @sumelic Or the fact that the password is visible as plain text.

Comment: @WadCheber In the movies he is not "out and proud" in Rorschach's second journal entry of the movie he literally says "Adrian Veidt...possible homosexual...must investigate further." If Rorschach can suspect Ozymandias of being a homosexual that clearly means that he has not come out.

Comment: @MrLister Reading the comic, the only way to see what he was typing was for it to be in plain text.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe Adrian wanted the files to be found so to lead the others to Karnak. If he said "Come to Karnak I have something to show you" then they may be suspicious of a trap. Doing it this way they feel they have the upper hand and so be more comfortable with the meeting.

Comment: How did you come to these conclusions? Can you provide any sources to got you to this conclusion?

Comment: Well. It was essential for Dr Manhatten to come to Karnak so that he would be assigned the blame for the destruction. If he was unknowing of the plot then he might try and 'fix' things and as such trigger a war between himself and the superpowers which Would prob involve nuclear weapons.
As for the others - they might try and protect Manhatten's reputation and likewise unstabalise Veights plot. So they would have to know the reason for his disappearance.
With all of them at Karnak they would know the full reason behind the plot and so either agree to it.. or be eliminated.
I am speculating

Answer (score 0):

It's just Moore being clever. The recurring theme of that issue is "Two Riders"- Night Owl and Rorschach taking Archie to Antarctica, two people on horseback during the "Black Freighter" segment, the missionaries on bicycles, Nixon and Ford on Air Force One and Two... so the "rider" for the password is "II".

Also, the late '80s readers were not as tech-savvy. As was pointed out above, most people took "War Games" at face value.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The question is looking for the *in-universe* reason for Veidt to choose such an easy password.  Even if you're right about the theme that Moore is developing, it doesn't explain the _character's_ motivation, which is what the question is asking.

Comment: Once you have eliminated the Watsonian, whatever remains, however Doylist, must be the truth.