# What is the in-film explanation for Comedian's crying?

Tags: dc, adaptation-comparison, watchmen, watchmen-2009

In Alan Moore's graphic novel, the Comedian discovers a certain plot where

> Adrian Veidt

plans to use a psychic pseudo-alien squid to trick USSR and USA into peaceful coexistence.

This plan makes the Comedian realise that "it's all a joke".

Yet in the movie there is no squid in the first place, and we're not shown how the Comedian learns about the *other* (film-version) evil plan. We know he is aware of it, because of said scene and the fact that the Comedian is

> assassinated by Veidt,

but **how does the film explain the way Comedian became aware of said plot**?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Movie

In the *film version*, the method of his discovery isn't explained in any great detail. It seems that he gained access to Adrian's kill-list (somehow) and learned what was going on at Karnak (somehow). That suggests either a [hacking job](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/106593/why-did-adrian-veidt-choose-such-an-obvious-password) or that he somehow infiltrated one of Veidt's facilities around the world and pieced it together from files/interrogations

> **Comedian:** *And your name... **your name was on the list**... along with Janey, you
>   know, whatever the fuck her name is. Manhattan's old girl. Mother,
>   forgive me.*
>
> ...
>
> **Veidt:** *Blake figured it out first. **Nixon had him keeping tabs on us, making
>   sure we weren't rocking the boat. Blake found out what I was doing
>   here in Karnak** and by the time he visited poor Moloch, he was cracking
>   badly. Even I couldn't predict he'd be the one to have a change of
>   heart. So I had to kill him.*

---

### Graphic Novel

In the comic-book, this is rather more explicitly explained in [Watchmen 11; Look upon my works, ye Mighty...](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Watchmen_Vol_1_11) and [Before Watchmen: Ozymandias - Part 5: Look on my works, ye Mighty, and despair!](http://www.dccomics.com/comics/before-watchmen-ozymandias-2012/before-watchmen-ozymandias-5)

In short, Blake stumbled onto Veidt's research facility and worked it out from there.

[image]

[image]

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: I may have been unclear. I am well aware of the comic, in fact I'm going over it now. What has Blake stumbled upon in the **film** that made him crack?

Comment: @Gallifreian - He evidently worked out both parts of the plan; to discombobulate Manhattan and to blow up the facilities, killing millions. Personally, I reckon he hacked Veidt's computers. We know he's a muggins when it comes to passwords.

Comment: -  yet how? In the comic he "he swims to an island with a dagger in his teeth"; what does he do in the film? How did he learn of the plan to frame Dr. Manhattan?

Comment: I just noticed the edit and the film quote; that answers my question almost perfectly (apparently, Snyder didn't bother with an explanation in the first place, eh?)

Comment: If I could, I'd upvote this 3 times, for the film, comic, and *Before Watchmen*.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the past actions of the Comedian in the film. He is totally loyal to the government. Look at the fact that he assassinated Kennedy because Kennedy was thinking of closing down (or making less influential) the FBI. And so many other things he may have done under the guise of "For the good of the government". From his comments he is also very anticommunist.

Now he discovers a plot that not only goes against the government and his country, involves Russia, and forces both America and Russia to make peace and co-operate. All set up by people who he felt he could trust.

It would go against everything he believes in. There is no one who he can talk to (except past criminals like Moloch) which again aggravates his sense of betrayal.

Essentially - for a man who has charted his own destiny - he finds that he no-longer has control of his future. All that he has believed in is going to change and there is a high probability that he will not be a part of it.

So he starts to crack, and the others are faced that they will have to take him out.

If one considers Rorschach - The Comedian is almost his double except that the Comedian is on the side of 'Good' and Rorschach is on the side of 'Bad'.

Comment: I agree with you, save for the second paragraph - the plot was designed by Veidt alone, and Comedian never really trusted him.

Comment: Levels of trust then. He might not trust Veidt.. But the act of bringing a action of mass destruction and dragging Russia in to it would go against All the Comedian's values.